# Best practice - Meta Query vs. post_clauses for "left join" ordering

Tags: meta-query, customization

Moreso a psuedo-code question than actual code. I have some custom post meta attached to attachments, and created a list table column for this meta. The meta is either 1, or null (not  set), but I am trying to enable sorting for said column.

Is there a way to utilize `meta_query` for WP_Query to essentially LEFT JOIN, where I get all values (1 or null), and then I can utilize `orderby=meta_value_num` for ordering?

The obvious way it would work is hooking into posts_clauses, adding a JOIN, and doing the orderby as well - just curious if this would be possible while using direct WP_Query functionality!

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you adding a custom column (and to which table) when there's the `post_meta` table anyway? One entry equals one row in this table.

Comment: Media List Table, not database table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it either way!

Using `posts_clauses`, manually write your JOIN statement (using $wpdb->prepare() - be safe!) , and add/customize the `orderby` clause as well.

Using `meta_query` there are a couple things needed. First, as kaiser mentions, you must use `relation` within `meta_query` in order for it to work. Second, even though meta_query is defined, you still need to specify the `meta_key` argument, or else orderby=meta_value will not work. I assume this is because you can have multiple joins happening at once, which could be using different meta keys.

Here is how I accomplished it:

```
function handle_my_sortable_column( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if( is_admin() && 'upload.php' == $pagenow && 'my_meta_key' == get_query_var( 'orderby' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => my_meta_key',
                'value' => null,
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'my_meta_key',
                'value' => '', // must be '' value, null does not work
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        ) );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'my_meta_key' ); // required for orderby
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Afaik your only problem is that the `relation` is set to `AND` instead to `OR`. This should be the only thing you need to change.

Comment: Interesting - relation is found under `tax_query` but not `meta_query` - testing this now.

Comment: Updating my answer now.

Comment: Well, that the `value` needs to be defined empty is even stated in Codex ;)

Comment: it mentions trying both `null` and `''`. Thought I'd point out that bull didn't work for `NOT EXISTS` but did for `EXISTS` - strange.

Comment: It mentions "If empty quotes doesn't work, pass `null` to it" ... :)

Comment: Upvoted - you can already mark it as solution.

Comment: Cheers - had to wait the 2 days, and was away all weekend. Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pre_get_posts` with a callback:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/** Plugin Name: (#102854) Order Posts by Foo */

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_102854_orderby_foo' );
function wpse_102854_orderby_foo( $query )
{
    if ( 
        ! $query->is_main_query()
        OR ! is_admin()
        OR 'edit.php?post_type=YOUR_POST_TYPE' !== $GLOBALS['parent_file']
        // Other conditions that force an abort, Example:
        // OR 'foo' !== $query->get( 'some_query_var' )
    )
        return $query;

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    // etc.

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Correct. I think this will NOT work however. In order for this to work, meta_query would need to support 'join_type' or something similar. Right now 'Inner Join' is hard coded. wp-includes/meta.php line 731.

Comment: @EricHolmes [Take a look at this plugin I wrote, which supports "Match" and "Filter"](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/filterama/blob/master/inc/match.class.php) to get either posts with either ALL taxonomies attached or posts with ANY taxonomy attached. Should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks @kaiser, you pointed me in the right direction with `relation`. Updated my answer below with the correct method using `pre_get_posts`.